# Js обрезать строку после первого вхождения символа-метки

Tags: javascript

строка "s_2015-08-1_1_2" нужно оставить "2015-08-1_1_2"

сплитом разбивать на массив и удалять первый элемент, а потом снова собирать думаю не самое лучшее решение

не факт что значение до первого подчеркивания один символ

Comment: [indexOf](https://javascript.ru/String/indexOf) и [substr](http://javascript.ru/string/substr) вам в помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"s_2015-08-1_1_2".replace(/^[^_]*_/,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  s.substring(s.indexOf('_') + 1)
```